# How can this approach to solving circular dependencies in triggers (PostgreSQL) be improved?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

Let's say I have two tables, for the simplicity, let them be `authors` and `pages`. Listing only the interesting attributes like this:

```
CREATE TABLE authors (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    active BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT true, -- set by the author himself
    banned BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false, -- set to true by the site administrator
    visible BOOLEAN, -- set automatically in a trigger and used by the platform
                    -- when deciding whether to show this author or not.
                    -- Equals to (active and not banned).
    visible_pages INT -- counter also updated automatically
);

CREATE TABLE pages (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    ref_author INT NOT NULL,
    draft BOOLEAN DEFAULT true,
    archived BOOLEAN DEFAULT false, -- not draft but not published anymore
    visible BOOLEAN -- (authors.visible and not (draft or archived))
);
```

Now, when author publishes a page or archives it, the counter needs to be updated. When an author gets banned or suspends their account, the pages need to turn invisible. All that is done so that the frontend only cares for the `visible` flag and doesn't need to waste cycles to calculate it on the fly.

The straightforward (and somewhat naïve) way to make these triggers is as follows (the function names say it all, and trigger creation is omitted for brevity):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION before_update_authors() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.visible := (NEW.enabled AND NOT NEW.banned);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION after_update_authors() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.visible != OLD.visible THEN
        UPDATE pages SET id = id WHERE ref_author = NEW.id; -- dummy call just to trigger the trigger
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION before_update_pages() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE author_visible BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
    SELECT visible INTO author_visible FROM authors WHERE id = NEW.ref_author;
    NEW.visible := author_visible AND NOT (draft OR archived);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION after_update_pages() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE counter INT;
BEGIN
    IF OLD.visible <> NEW.visible THEN
        IF NEW.visible THEN
            counter := 1;
        ELSE
            counter := -1;
        END IF;
        UPDATE authors SET visible_pages = visible_pages + counter WHERE id = NEW.ref_author;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Looks straightforward, but in the best case it is slow, and in the worst case it would smash the stack and fail.

In MySQL we can get around this unfortunate situation by using @session_variables, so triggers can detect being called from triggers. PostgreSQL does not have such concept.

The best solution I have come up with so far is to use auxiliary columns and `WHEN` conditions. So my `pages` table grows an additional column, `_updating_author` of type `BOOLEAN` (default whatever but non-NULL).

Now the code for `*_update_pages` stays the same. The code to create trigger differs, though:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_before_update_pages BEFORE UPDATE ON pages WHEN (OLD._updating_author IS DISTINCT FROM NEW._updating_author) FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE before_update_pages();
CREATE TRIGGER tg_after_update_pages AFTER UPDATE ON pages WHEN (OLD._updating_author IS DISTINCT FROM NEW._updating_author) FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE after_update_pages();
```

And so is trigger function after_update_authors():

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION after_update_authors() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.visible != OLD.visible THEN
        UPDATE pages SET visible = (NEW.visible AND NOT (draft OR archived)), _updating_authors = NOT _updating_authors WHERE ref_author = NEW.id;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In this case, pages visibility is being set in batch and very fast, because no trigger will be called for individual rows in `pages`.

However, the need for auxiliary columns bothers me a bit in this approach, and WHEN conditions seem a bit clunky. So is the need to state the logic of what `pages.visible` is twice.

Can you please suggest an alternative, maybe more elegant, approach to solving this and similar problems?

Comment: Perhaps a solution based on a view, instead of triggers, would be better. I'm not quite sure what the rule is for visible_pages, that looks like the only sticking point.

Comment: Basically count(0) from pages where ref_author = id and visible.  A view won't do because aggregates are expensive.

Comment: I'd worry about premature optimization. Anyway, I suggest that you use `visible_pages` for the number of pages that would be visible _if the author is visible_. Under your program logic, if an invisible author adds a page and later becomes visible, that page remains invisible. Is that the intended behavior?

Comment: It won't remain invisible if you trace the logic. Note, also, that I'm not asking to help me solve a specific problem, I'm talking about a generic class of problems under the "circular dependency between tables and triggers" umbrella.